# Yadr - oh my zsh - command not found

Tags: path, npm, zsh, yadr

My system was installed by a friend and I have very low knowledge about linux system since I'm most used to Windows. I am on a Yosemite mac.  My node was installed by `brew install node`, I have npm installed and from jslint install I get this error:

```
zsh: correct jslint to slit [nyae]? n
zsh: command not found: jslint
```

The fix seems to be [from this website](http://www.bwigg.com/category/javascript/), a directory to PATH must be added.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/bin:${PATH}"
```

I have low knowledge about the location of that file. Can I get where to find it or some introductory explanation?

Running echo $PATH; I get:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Users/frontend/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin:/Users/frontend/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/bin:/Users/frontend/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/frontend/.rvm/bin:/Users/frontend/.yadr/bin:/Users/frontend/.yadr/bin/yadr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From web this is the [source](https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689) that gave me a hint how to fix it.

1. ls -a
2. vi .bash_profile
3. Add `export PATH="$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH"`
4. Then install again `npm install -g jslint`